# select join multiple rows into single row

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

i have a table like this

**users**

```
name   |  phone   |  email
jane   | 123456   |jane@test.com
jack   | 223456   |jack @test.com
```

i want to select these two users given their phone number which is unique, go give

```
borrower  |  lender   |  email
name      |  jack     | jane@test.com
```

this is what i tried

```
SELECT  u1.name borrower,u1.email, u2.name lender  FROM users u1  
LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.phone='123456' WHERE u1.phone='223456'
```

this gave me 4 rows instead of one what could be wrong?

Comment: "several rows into 1 row" = `GROUP BY`, "select only 2 rows" = `LIMIT 2`

Comment: what will i group by, there is no unique column here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0105/1)**

```
SELECT 
  u1.name borrower,
  u1.email, 
  u2.name lender 
FROM 
  users u1, 
  users u2 
WHERE 
  u2.phone='123456' 
  and 
  u1.phone='223456'
;
```

---

[image]

Comment: i got the same result, 4 rows

Comment: If you got 4 rows, then I would guess that you have the same rows twice in your users table. Please do select * from users to check that. Clean up your table or do a distinct query like `select distinct u1.name borrower...`

Comment: thank you, i found out that one of the number has duplicate records